# Replace certain text with value if text in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm just getting  up to speed on Pandas and cannot resolve one issue.  I have a list of Counties in NY State.  If the County is one of the 5 boroughs, I want to change the county name to New York, otherwise I leave it alone.  The following gives the idea, but is not correct.

EDIT - so if the counties in the County column of the first few rows were Albany, Allegheny, Bronx before the change, they would be Albany, Allegheny, New York after the change

```
# clean up county names
# 5 boroughs must be combined to New York City
# eliminate the word county
nyCounties = ["Kings", "Queens", "Bronx", "Richmond", "New York"]

nypopdf['County'] = ['New York' for nypopdf['County'] in nyCounties else   
nypopdf['County']]
```

Comment: can you show your expected output from that list ?

Comment: also - this comment in your code looks like a mistake `#nypopdf['County'] = ['New York' for nypopdf['County'] in nyCounties else `. you Probably meant to have `#nypopdf['County'] = ['New York' for nypopdf['County'] in nyCounties else nypopdf['County']]`

Comment: nypopdf['County'] = ['New York' for nypopdf['County'] in nyCounties else nypopdf['County']]  results in a syntax error at else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small mockup:

```
In [44]: c = ['c', 'g']
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame({'county': list('abccdefggh')})
In [46]: df['county'] = df['county'].where(~df['county'].isin(c), 'N')
In [47]: df
Out[47]:   county
         0      a
         1      b
         2      N
         3      N
         4      d
         5      e
         6      f
         7      N
         8      N
         9      h
```

So this is using [pd.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) `~df['county'].isin(c)` selects rows that are not in the list `c` (the `~` at the start is the 'not' operation), the second argument is the value to replace with (when the condition is False).

To fit your example:

```
nypopdf['County'] = nypopdf['County'].where(~nypopdf['County'].isin(nyCounties), 'New York')
```

or

```
nypopdf['County'].where(~nypopdf['County'].isin(nyCounties), 'New York', inplace=True)
```

Complete example:

```
nypopdf = pd.DataFrame({'County': ['Albany', 'Allegheny', 'Bronx']})
nyCounties = ["Kings", "Queens", "Bronx", "Richmond", "New York"]
print(nypopdf)
      County
0     Albany
1  Allegheny
2      Bronx
nypopdf['County'].where(~nypopdf['County'].isin(nyCounties), 'New York', inplace=True)
print(nypopdf)
      County
0     Albany
1  Allegheny
2   New York
```